# How to set value to a state variable inside a function in react

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, axios, setstate

I am getting a backend response to get the driver details using Axios and once after getting that I want to get the name, address of the driver. For that, I tried to set the value to a state variable but couldn't be able to assign, and also I have tried assigned the values to an array state variable and to access them later but I was unable to get a result

This is the code snippet:

```
    getDriverInfo = async () => {
    var session = sessionStorage.getItem("session");
    var apiBaseUrl = "http://localhost:4000/api/";
    // var self = this;
    let det = [];
    var payload = {
      nic: session,
    };

    axios
      .post(apiBaseUrl + "driverDetails", payload)
      .then(async (response) => {
        console.log(response.data.success);

        if (response.data.code == 204) {
          console.log("Driver Data retrieved successfull");
          
          response.data.success.map((element) => {
            det.push(element);
            this.state.Ddetails.push(element);
            
          });
          
          console.log(det.length);
          console.log(this.state.Ddetails[0].dln);
           await this.setState({
             fname: this.state.Ddetails[0].fName,
             lname: this.state.Ddetails[0].lName,
           });
          
        } else {
          console.log("Details does not exists");
          alert("Details does not exist");
        }
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
    
    console.log(det.length);
    this.state.Ddetails.map((item) => {
      console.log("Map");
      console.log(item.dln);
    });
    console.log(this.state.Ddetails.dln);
  };
```

Comment: use setState( { Ddetails : ....})

Comment: It is not a good practice to directly mutate the React state : this.state.Ddetails.push(element). Please read the documentation first before you ask a question.

Comment: @EddwinPaz That also didn't work

Answer (score 0):

**Don't update state directly** this is an anty pattern.

https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly

I have modified your code a little.

```js
getDriverInfo = async () => {
    var session = sessionStorage.getItem("session");
    var apiBaseUrl = "http://localhost:4000/api/";
    // var self = this;
    let det = [];
    var payload = {
      nic: session,
    };

    axios
      .post(apiBaseUrl + "driverDetails", payload)
      .then(async (response) => {
        console.log(response.data.success);

        if (response.data.code == 204) {
          console.log("Driver Data retrieved successfull");
          
          response.data.success.map((element) => {
            det.push(element);
            //Don't use like this ==> this.state.Ddetails.push(element);
          });
          this.setState({Ddetails:det},()=>{
              console.log(det.length);
              console.log(this.state.Ddetails[0].dln);
              this.setState(prevState=>{
                  console.log(det.length);
                  prevState.Ddetails.map((item) => {
                      console.log("Map");
                      console.log(item.dln);
                  });
                 console.log(prevState.Ddetails.dln);
                  return{
                      fname: prevState[0].fName,
                      lname: prevState[0].lName,
                  }
              });
          })
        } else {
          console.log("Details does not exists");
          alert("Details does not exist");
        }
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
```

Comment: Thank you, Sorry I'm new to React. I have tried your code but I'm getting the following error: 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'fName' of undefined
 348 |   });
  349 |   console.log(prevState.Ddetails.dln);
  350 |   return {
> 351 |     fname: prevState[0].fName,
      | ^  352 |     lname: prevState[0].lName,
  353 |   };
  354 | });

Comment: It always feels good to learn something new! About the errors, you may need to debug a little. I modified your code by looking but for data, I am not sure what shape or form you are getting from the API. May be putting a snipped of your data would help to answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.state = {
   name: 'mickey',
   lastName: 'mouse',
};

const display = () => {
  // wont work
  console.log(this.state.name, this.state.lastName);
}

function display() {
    // will work
    console.log(this.state.name, this.state.lastName);
}
```

As you can see arrow functions wont work with (this)